# Need help fixing titlebar removing script (AutoHotkey)

Tags: autohotkey

I made a script that removes the title-bar: http://pastebin.com/yBTp5QML

But it doesn't work properly. I want it so that it opens automatically without a title-bar and then able to press Left Windows button and right click to make the title-bar re-appear

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the auto-execute portion in a loop... it's executing indefinitely.

Might try something like this...

```
#Persistent

WinSet, Style, -0xC00000, A
return

;+Caption
LWIN & RButton::
WinSet, Style, +0xC00000, A
return
;
```